# How to display multiple SKMapView maps simultaneously?

Tags: ios, skmaps

I have screen with multiple maps at same time. I add two subviews, but оnly one of the maps is drawn and recives gestures. Using ScoutMaps-iOS-SDK 3.0.2.

Screen, with test: https://puu.sh/uwmpm/7b0a3520c5.png

Answer (score 1):

As of now, this doesn't seem supported:

> Multiple independent SKMapView instances visible at the same time. The SDK supports one visible SKMapView instance at a time. Viewing multiple map instances in the same screen will result in an undefined behaviour.

Source : [Skobbler.com](https://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/ios#sec36)